# How to use std::regex_match with CString?

Tags: c++, regex, mfc

When I try to use std::regex with CString (MFC) I get this error:

[image]

And this is the code:

```
const std::regex pattern("^[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$");

const CString& csTest = "28.10.1991";

if (std::regex_match(csTest, pattern))
```

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13320/Using-Regular-Expressions-in-MFC

Comment: Use `CAtlRegExp` instead of `std::regex`

Comment: or [`boost::regex`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/non_std_strings/mfc_strings/mfc_intro.html)

Comment: To elaborate a bit, you are receiving this error because `std::regex_match` only works with iterators and standard library strings. CString is a Microsoft-ism (from MFC) and is not part of standard C++.

Comment: The `pattern` will match dates, that aren't. Like `99.99.1991`, or `00.00.2020`. A regular expression isn't going to solve [your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61349477/1889329). You need an unambiguous date representation, ideally without the possibility of invalid data. Like [year_month_day](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_day).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to you regex to extract just the name from a CString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68962121/how-to-you-regex-to-extract-just-the-name-from-a-cstring)

Answer (score 1):

There's no unambiguous conversion of `CString` to the first parameter of any of `std::regex_match` overloads.

Add `GetString()` to convert to const TCHAR* explicitly:

```
std::regex_match(csTest.GetString(), pattern)
```

Or, if you want to make use of iterator range (which could be a micro-optimization) use `GetLength()` in addition:

```
std::regex_match(csTest.GetString(), csTest.GetString() + csTest.GetLength(), pattern)
```

A comment recommends using `CAtlRegExp`. You can do this too, but note that `CAtlRegExp` has non-standard syntax, and also it has some bugs, and even no longer a part of ATL that ships with Visual Studio (part of "ATL server" that is separate from ATL starting Visual Studio 2008). So I would not use `CAtlRegExp`.

Answer (score -1):

There is another error in the regex: 
The dot matches any character, so the regex matches also "1234567890" and "12x34y5678" which are indeed not valid dates.
The dot must be escaped.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/

Use : 
`const std::regex pattern("^[0-9][0-9]\\.[0-9][0-9]\\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$");`

As the others said, convert the csTest CString into a C string, while CString is the MFC string class and C string is a C language conformant string:

```
if (std::regex_match(csTest.GetString(), pattern)) ...
```