# How to you regex to extract just the name from a CString?

Tags: regex, visual-c++, mfc, c-strings

Take a `CString` that has the following definition:

```
CString strNameText = _T("Mr Happy [12]");
```

I have a series of names with all have the space with a number is brackets at the end. Now I want to extract just the name from the string.

I realise that I can find the first index of `" ["` and then extract the text on the left up to that index. But can I use any regex command to do the same?

Comment: ```[A-Za-z ]+``` this includes the space at the side of ```[``` is this okay for you?

Comment: @GhostOps Thanks. I don't want the trailing spece at the end of the name. I am also not sure how to perform an actual regex operation.

Comment: ```([A-Za-z]+ ?\b)``` now this one ignores unwanted trailing spaces, and even i don't know to perform a regex operation in c++, sry

Comment: Is this an academic interest? For such a simple pattern, I'm sure regex is an overkill.

Comment: @vlad. No I had need for this. And I did not want to split the word manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might suggest a regex replacement here, to remove the bracketed term at the end of the string.

```
std::string strNameText ("Mr Happy [12]");
std::regex r ("\\s+\\[\\d+\\]$");
std::cout << std::regex_replace (strNameText, r, "");  // Mr Happy
```

---

#### C++ Example

```
#include <regex>

CString strNameText = _T("Mr Happy [12]");

std::string s1 = CT2A(strNameText);
std::regex r("\\s+\\[\\d+\\]$");
std::string s2 = std::regex_replace(s1, r, "");

return CString(s2.c_str());
```

Comment: Thanks. How do a pass a `CString` into the `regex_replace` function?

Comment: I tried `std::regex_replace(strNameText.GetString(), r, "");` and it doesn't like it.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I'm not a C++ person, but AFAIK `std::string` is the same thing as a `CString`.

Comment: I added c++ version to your answer

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's not the same thing at all, but both are c++ classes that implement string handling. CString is the from MFC and std::string is the standard C++ class.